# Where can i find the ThreadPool.SwitchTo method?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, threadpool, async-ctp

I am studying the new Async CTP and going through some sample code,

I came across this piece of code:

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
string text = txtInput.Text; 

await ThreadPool.SwitchTo(); // jump to the ThreadPool 

string result = ComputeOutput(text); 
string finalResult = ProcessOutput(result); 

await txtOutput.Dispatcher.SwitchTo(); // jump to the TextBox’s thread 

txtOutput.Text = finalResult; 
}
```

Please where do I find ThreadPool.SwitchTo? SwithcTo method is not on the ThreadPool class

i have a referece to AsyncCtpLibrary.dll ... but no luck

Comment: It looks like an extension method to me.

Comment: Assuming you've got the code loaded in Visual Studio, right-click on the name of the method and select "Go To Definition". It will take you immediately to where that method is defined so that you can study it. I suspect chibacity's supposition that it's an extension method defined elsewhere than the `ThreadPool` class is correct.

Comment: so i though, but from where? i have added a reference to the AsyncCtpLibrary.dll but no luck

Comment: You have to add the correct `using` to use extension methods.

Comment: guys, im working (studying) with the Async CTP, i have all the references set up correctly, but even a right click does'nt resolve the issue i have googled for the Switch to method of the Threadpool class...no luck

Comment: OK, found it guys,
Summary:
Provides methods for interacting with the ThreadPool.

Remarks:
ThreadPoolEx is a placeholder.

Comment: Public Shared Function SwitchTo() As System.Runtime.CompilerServices.YieldAwaitable
     Member of System.Threading.ThreadPoolEx
Summary:
Creates an awaitable that asynchronously yields to the ThreadPool when awaited.

Comment: @CharlesO: If you've figured it out, post it as an answer to help others in the future.

Comment: @chibacity, @Cody: Wait, what? When did extension methods on static classes become possible?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, CharlesO answered his question within the comments above:

> OK, found it guys, Summary: Provides
>   methods for interacting with the
>   ThreadPool. Remarks: ThreadPoolEx is a
>   placeholder.
>
> Public Shared Function SwitchTo() As
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.YieldAwaitable
>   Member of
>   System.Threading.ThreadPoolEx Summary:
>   Creates an awaitable that
>   asynchronously yields to the
>   ThreadPool when awaited.

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadPool.SwitchTo` was removed presumably because it is an anit-pattern. Consider what would happen if an exception were thrown before you switched back to the original context. You cannot use a `finally` block as a counter measure to guard against that exception and switch back because `await` cannot appear in `finally` blocks.

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  await ThreadPool.SwitchTo();
  try
  {
    // Do something dangerous here.
  }
  finally
  {
    await button1.Dispatcher.SwitchTo(); // COMPILE ERROR!
  }

}
```

You can, of course, develop custom awaitable and awaiter types to achieve exactly what was removed. However, it is far better to use `Task.Run`<sup>1</sup> than to switch contexts midstream via `await`.